# SQL Server - Merge Multiple Roles into One

Tags: sql-server

I would like to merge multiple rows into one row per ID, but I cannot use the `FOR XML PATH('')` as I want to include a tooltip ''. The result will be used in a hover box that is why I need the tooltip.

I have tried the `FOR XML PATH('')`, but this does not work for the purposes of what I am using the result in.

Original Table

```
ID   Name
---------------
1    One_A
2    Two_A
2    Two_B
3    Three_A
3    Three_B
3    Three_C
```

Resulting desired output:

```
ID    Summary
--------------------------------------------------
1     One_A
2     Two_A &#013; Two_B &#013;
3     Three_A &#013; Three_B &#013; Three_C &#013;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: "I have tried the FOR XML PATH()".  I don't see any query posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear why you have the trailing `&#013;` on 2 and 3 but not 1

I suspect you were missing the `TYPE`

Also, in the example, we have `Order By ID`.  You may need **TRUE** sequence key otherwise you may not be able to GTD the order

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[Name] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'One_A')
,(2,'Two_A')
,(2,'Two_B')
,(3,'Three_A')
,(3,'Three_B')
,(3,'Three_C')

Select A.ID
      ,Summary  = Stuff((Select ' &#013; ' +[Name] 
                           From  @YourTable 
                           Where ID=A.ID 
                           Order by ID 
                           For XML Path(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
                        ,1,8,'') 
 From @YourTable A
 Group By ID
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Summary
1   One_A
2   Two_A &#013; Two_B
3   Three_A &#013; Three_B &#013; Three_C
```

Comment: Worked perfect thank you so much, literally lost half a day trying to figure this one out!! thanks

Comment: @JustinHeath Happy to help.  We've all been stuck in the mud.  There is no shame in asking for a little push.